# FFMPEG SilenceDetect

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to understand the output obtained from FFMPEG. A part of the output, I obtained is as shown below.

```
[null @ 000000000449e740] Encoder did not produce proper pts, making some up
[silencedetect @ 00000000048263a0] silence_start: -0.00356009
[silencedetect @ 00000000048263a0] silence_end: 11.4242 | silence_duration:11.4278
[silencedetect @ 00000000048263a0] silence_start: 11.7457
[silencedetect @ 00000000048263a0] silence_end: 11.8422 | silence_duration: 0.0964399
[silencedetect @ 00000000048263a0] silence_start: 12.1173
.....
[silencedetect @ 00000000048263a0] silence_end: 113.708 | silence_duration: 0.14288
[silencedetect @ 00000000048263a0] silence_start: 113.751
frame= 3254 fps=297 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:02:10.17 bitrate=N/A    
video:305kB audio:22424kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

I understand that, silence_start gives the timestamp at which silence in the audio file is detected and silence_end gives the ending timestamp. I have two questions here

1) How come the timestamp for the first silence_start has a negative value?(-0.00356009)

2)In the last line of the output I could see the silence_start is at 113.751, but unable to see the silence_end. Why is it so?

Answer (score 5):

> How come the timestamp for the first silence_start has a negative value?(-0.00356009)

Because the file you're working on does not seem to have presentation timestamps (PTS) for the frames/samples set. This is what the warning in the first line says. ffmpeg will generate some PTS, but these may not be accurate.

> In the last line of the output I could see the silence_start is at 113.751, but unable to see the silence_end. Why is it so?

Have you considered that most—if not all—sound files end with silence? So ffmpeg detects the start of silence just before the end of the file, and then reaches the file's end.